# Adobe Air 2.5 and AIR Debug Launcher (ADL) from AIR 1.5.3 SDK

Tags: apache-flex, air

I am having some issues with the differences between running my Air Desktop application with the ADL from within my IDE and actually running it as an packaged air application that is installed. Everything functions as it should in the IDE when run with ADL, but once it is packaged the drag and drop functionality no longer works correctly.

I was able to get this to work when Adobe Air 1.5 runtime was installed, instead of 2.5. I am aware that there were a lot of changes made with this last update, but I am unsure of how to proceed, as I am unable to debug the packaged air application to see what is actually happening.

One solution that I could see would be to install the Adobe Air 2.5 SDK and use that to debug with.

If anyone has any insight to why drag and drop works in the ADL and the runtime, your feedback would be much appreciated.

Also, I am using Flash Builder 4, with the Flex 3.5 SDK

Answer (score 1):

If something doesn't work when compiled, it's usually because you've used a feature only allowed for natively packaged AIR applications. Try packaging it as a native file using this guide and see if it works:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS789ea67d3e73a8b22388411123785d839c-8000.html

Essentially all you'll need to do is:

Check this line in your app.xml file and make sure it is uncommented and set to extendedDesktop like below:

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>
```

and then on the command line call:

ADT -package -target native mynewfilepath/myFile.exe myfilepath/myFile.air

[ADT is found within your flex sdk folder.]